# IBM MQ Client c# and cipherspec

Tags: ibm-mq

I am trying to connect to a queuemanger over TLS1.2 using version 9.1.5 of the IBM MQ dotnet libraries.
I am able to connect when using "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256" as I can see using wire shark that this is the cipher that is being negotiated with the queuemanager. I can see that we send a list of ciphers and the server responds with "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256".

If the provider sets "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256" on the SVRCONN channel, then we are able to connect

Is there anyway we can force this to use TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P256?

The history to this is that our provider wants to specify ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 on the SVRCONN channel and our connection is failing after the handshake is complete according to [Cipher Spec Mappings for the managed .net client](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q120630_.htm)

This is the version that is being enforced on the 
We tried editing the group policy but it seems to be appending the defaults onto the end of the list we are sending.

Can anyone help? Is there something I am missing?

Thanks,
K

Comment: It is all policy based if you are using `amqmdnet.dll`, you would need to get the cipher you want to be presented prior to the one you see selected.  I have not yet used the  .NET standard dll, this may be possible there.

Comment: I have also tried to use 9.1.3 with dotnet framework. What do you mean by policy based?

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q120610_.htm

Comment: I mean with a managed .net client your only way to control things is to influence the list of ciphers and the order they are presented via the windows group policy and this impacts the whole windows server not just your application. This [blog by Colin Paice](https://colinpaice.blog/2020/04/05/should-i-specify-which-cipher-suites-my-web-browser-should-use-or-the-opposite/) gives a good explanation of this negotiation between a TLS client (your app) and a TLS server (the queue manger), note he is discussing a browser (TLS client) and a web server (TLS server) but the concept is the same.

Comment: Thanks for this. We are seeing where we are sending a list of cipher specs and the server is not picking the one we would expect. Is there a way we can get the queuemanger to change which one it picks?

Comment: The only possible queue manager way would be to use the new 9.1.1 or higher way of specifying the list of ciphers you want the queue manger overall to accept and remove those you do not want,  but this is global for the queue manager.

Comment: Another work around could be to put a MQIPT in the middle, this could present only the cipher you want to use to your client and also present the same to the queue manager.

Comment: Is the cipher picked prior to the cipher you want in the list sent?  If so this is working as designed for TLS.

Comment: What do you mean by new 9.1.1 way of specifying the list of ciphers? Do you mean the client?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214248/discussion-between-jumpercake-and-joshmc).

Comment: No on the queue manager. 
 " The only possible queue manager way would be to use the new 9.1.1 or higher way of specifying the list of ciphers you want the queue manger overall to accept" see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q014260_.htm#q014260___alwtls

Comment: It would help if you can provide the list of ciphers sent in the client hello and the server hello.

Comment: Hi JoshMc, we managed to this working late yesterday evening. The group policy is now working. Just to note, when we were passing the ciperspec from our application, we needed to pass the IBM cipher spec from the mapping table - ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA256. It then picked up the policy settings when sending the list of ciphers

Comment: What value did you pass to MQ when it was not working, was it `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P256`? Which Windows version are you at?  What value did you specify in the group policy when it was not working vs now?

Comment: We were passing TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P256 using client version 9.1.5. When we passed that cipher, the group policy had no effect. When we passed ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, the policy then worked.